# Loading single feature from server - layer property is missing

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I have a layer that consists of a few 100 features, of which only those are loaded that fit into a bounding box. Later, I want to check on the server side, whether a specific feature with a specific attribute exists and then zoom to that feature.

I am not sure about the appropriate way how to do this, so I just call the read function of my layer's protocol, with a filter parameter. The result looks fine at first, but the retrieved feature seems to be inclompete, it lacks for example a vale for the `layer` property.

Do I need some other attributes on the read-functions' option parameter? Or is there a simpler approach to the problem?

```
var mylayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
        strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
        protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            url : baseurl + "/wfs",
            version : "1.1.0",
            featureType : "myfeature",
            featureNS : 'myNS',
            srsName :"EPSG:4326",

        }),
        renderers : ["Canvas"],
    });



 ......

  var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
    type : OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
    property : "myProp",
    value : 123
    });

    mylayer.protocol.read({

      filter : filter,

      callback : function(resp) {

         console.log(resp.features[0]);

      }

    });
```